# Downvoted on an answer to my own question!

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

I'd really like to know, after posting the answer to my own question (after much searching, and no help from the community) with the **actual** answer? I'd still have 2 reputation points if I **didn't** post the answer. That is not contributing to the community -- it is punishing and not encouraging the sharing of knowledge.

Here is the question: [IE is not centering text in a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304985/ie-is-not-centering-text-in-a-table-cell)

I can't "accept" my answer until tomorrow. :(

Comment: We'll probably never know. People downvote stuff for all kinds of reasons. Just ignore it and go on.

Comment: Sage advice, but it still irks me.

Comment: LOL! I even get downvoted on a perfectly legitimate question/gripe. Oh, Meta, how I love thee!

Comment: I see [Lucifer beat me to too it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17305619/revisions), but I was going to suggest removing the conversational tone and the ". Don't know how, don't know why -- that is just Internet Explorer's way of saying "Have a nice day!" :)" nonsense.  Someone probably downvoted the commentary.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thank you for the possible explanation. I am just that sort of person, I try to inject humor to lighten the mood. (I guess too often.) Lucifer, thanks for the edit.

Comment: And in case you don't know, [voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).  You might have been downvoted because someone disagreed with your post, or dislike the ranty tone of this question.

Comment: You got one downvote which you didn't deserve. What should we do about it? What do you propose? What is your question?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Oh, that I know -- meta is a whole other beast. But, thank you for stating that.

Comment: @DanielDaranas The question is: How could it be possible that a correct answer (the only one, at least on the page) could actually be downvoted?

Comment: @dihakz, by someone pressing the downvote button?

Comment: @Tomas Gee, I didn't think of that. Seriously, in the real world, if I asked you why the sky was blue and you answered "the presence of oxygen in the atmosphere absorbs most wavelengths of visible light, and scatters the blue shades" -- that would be an actual, correct answer. Does it make sense for someone to say "boooo, I don't like the answer"?

Comment: Why do you think that your answer is correct? You've removed the width attribute, which could result in changing the size of the column, not only the text center. The question was about text centering, the answers that impose changing something unrelated to problem are usually considered bad and therefore downvoted.

Comment: @dihakz _Your_ opinion is that your answer is correct. How do you know that _you_ are right? Maybe someone else thought that the answer was "Not useful" (that is the exact meaning of a downvote - read the tooltip). The usefulness or non-usefulness of an answer, as seen by different people, is expressed in their votes. If you disagree with a downvote, try to convince other people to upvote you, by improving your answer, commenting it, etc. But in the end you can't prevent anyone from downvoting if they don't find it useful.

Comment: My answer was correct because I wanted to center text, and nothing I did would center it in IE, until I removed that attribute. Had someone suggested that, until I found it myself, I would have been thrilled and upvoted/accepted the answer.

Comment: @dihakz Your answer _solves_ your problem. As the asker, you have the privilege to _accept_ it. But votes are democratic, you can't control them in any way. They express the usefulness of an answer as viewed by _the community_. I'm not arguing with you, this is just how things work.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I'm slowly starting to learn that. 1+1=2 is not always correct here. It would only be someone's opinion of what 1+1 equals. And if 1+1 is stated to actually be equal to 2, it can be "not useful" to someone, so they downvote it.

Comment: Please don't let a single downvote get you down. Answering your own question is absolutely the right thing to do. If the answer is truly helpful you will be vindicated in the end.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you for the encouragement -- I really needed it. :)

Answer (score 5):

The site grants certain right to users, as to make a community decision about value of almost everything on here. This does mean that sometimes a person will consider something worth a, for instance, downvote while you'd consider it worth something else, e.g. an upvote.

That's the whole deal around here: everyone with certain rep can vote, but not everyone votes the same. Together you'd get some sort of average?

Therefore there is no real thing to answer. It was not an 'illegal' downvote (for instance: drive by // multi downvote as revenge), just one you don't agree with.

Points to consider

- The tone of your answer (before it was edited) could be the reason. Hard to argue with that.
- It could be someone thought your solution worked only for your case, but the similar problem that let the user to your answer wasn't helped.
- The user thought one of the other answers was better

There is no special case for the answers of the OP, they are not regarded higher then the others.  THe crux is that here you consider this "the only correct answer", but you are not the one decide that.

Comment: I don't agree with your logic, here. It wasn't an opinion or a wrong answer nor nonconstructive. It simply **answered** the question. Had I not posted the answer, there would be none there. Isn't what I did the responsible thing to do? I know I would want to see the correct answer if I came across it!  As for the individual points for consideration: The first point is the only one that seems pertinent. There was no other acceptable answer on the page (none of them fixed the problem) and the answer I posted actually did answer the question. All the same, thank you for the insight.

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that you cannot rule in absolutes here. The whole idea of the site is that things like "wrong answer", "correct answer" are not decided by unit-test or anything, but by popular vote. So it doesn't matter if in a real-world test it actually did fix the problem: someone thought the answer wasn't usefull. He/she could be wrong, but has the right to be wrong. There is no appeal-to-downvote here, so its "the system" as it is.

Comment: Thank you for that last explanation. Though it is illogical to me (like downvoting 2+2=4) and really does not help to contribute to the conversation or help anyone, nor offers an alternative that worked as well. I did, however, learn more about this community, by your comment: SO is all about the "popular" answer, not necessarily the correct one. Okay, I'll bear that in mind from this point forward.

Comment: @dihark If you don't like SO, you may as well use a different Q&A site.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Au contraire! I love SO, I just don't like many of the rules governing how things operate. I like that it is democratic, I like that there are so many willing people to help. I like that I can help others. I also like that it is not cluttered up with too many duplicates or opinion-based questions and answers. In the future, I'm less likely to post my own answer to my question, since I've been penalized by doing so. Don't you think there is something wrong with that?

Comment: @dihaks You don't seem to like that it is democratic. Someone gave a vote which you disagree with (btw, in a question which has a score of +1 already: 3 upvotes, 2 downvotes) and you are complaining about this fact.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I don't want to belabor this any longer (it is a pointless waste of time for everybody.) I appreciate your attentiveness to my issue, honestly. My question was more logic-based than anything else (hence my 2+2 analogy). I'd hoped that this was not a community of grumpy people that would be upset by an answer someone gave that actually solved the problem. It just doesn't make a lot of sense. I'll stop griping, though. You're right, at least it is +1. (I wish I could just accept the answer, already, to make it stand out and help anyone else with the same problem.)